# cant seem to Deserialize to strongly typed list object from array

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to deserialize use the following Json and classes:

```
List<Root> OBJTEST = (List<Root>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response, typeof(List<Root>));
```

Classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class Root 
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("Time Series (Daily)")]
    public TimeSeriesDaily TimeSeriesDaily { get; set; }
}     

[DataContract]
public class MetaData
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string _1Information { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
    public string _2Symbol { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
    public string _3LastRefreshed { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("4. Output Size")]
    public string _4OutputSize { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("5. Time Zone")]
    public string _5TimeZone { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class _20220203
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public string _1Open { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public string _2High { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public string _3Low { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public string _4Close { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
    public string _5Volume { get; set; }
}

public class _20220202
{
    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public string _1Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public string _2High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public string _3Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public string _4Close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
    public string _5Volume { get; set; }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "IBM",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2022-02-04",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2022-02-04": {
        "1. open": "137.8600",
        "2. high": "138.8200",
        "3. low": "136.2150",
        "4. close": "137.1500",
        "5. volume": "4142045"
    },
    "2022-02-03": {
        "1. open": "137.0000",
        "2. high": "138.7600",
        "3. low": "135.8310",
        "4. close": "137.7800",
        "5. volume": "6100777"
    }
  }
}
```

I could not get above to work
sourcing : "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo"

The objective is to return a `List<Root>` of strongly typed objects.

Comment: // getting error on below
                //Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RestApiSampleTest.Root]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Please add a sample of the json you're trying to deserialize and your `Root` classes to your question

Comment: Hi thanks, you can see the json by going to this url : https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo

Comment: I created a class object by going to https://json2csharp.com, but it creates a giant class which I believe is incorrect

Comment: when I go to the above site  json2csharp.com to create my class automatically how can I generate so it doesnt create all possible cases of the json this clearly seems not right to me

Comment: also how do I turn it into a LIST ? I tried this List<Root> obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(response);

Comment: The root object is not a list. Within it, you have the property `Time Series (Daily)` which you can deserialize as `Dictionary<DateTime, TimeSeries>` and you can rename one of your classes (say `_20220203`) as `TimeSeries`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an array value there. You should deserialize to object `Root obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response)`.

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "IBM",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2022-02-04",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2022-02-04": {
        "1. open": "137.8600",
        "2. high": "138.8200",
        "3. low": "136.2150",
        "4. close": "137.1500",
        "5. volume": "4142045"
    },
    "2022-02-03": {
        "1. open": "137.0000",
        "2. high": "138.7600",
        "3. low": "135.8310",
        "4. close": "137.7800",
        "5. volume": "6100777"
    }
  }
}
```

Try to parse `Time Series (Daily)` as `Dictionary<string, object>`

```
  {
"Meta Data": {
    "Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "Symbol": "IBM",
    "Last Refreshed": "2022-02-04",
    "Output Size": "Compact",
    "Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2022-02-04": {
        "open": "137.8600",
        "high": "138.8200",
        "low": "136.2150",
        "close": "137.1500",
        "volume": "4142045"
    },
    "2022-02-03": {
        "open": "137.0000",
        "high": "138.7600",
        "low": "135.8310",
        "close": "137.7800",
        "volume": "6100777"
    }
  }
}
```

If you want enumerate object then you can use JsonDocument:

```
        var jDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(content, new JsonDocumentOptions() { CommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip, AllowTrailingCommas = true });
        var root = jDoc.RootElement.EnumerateObject();
```

From the discussion in the comment, I believe it will help:

```
[DataContract]
public class Root 
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("Time Series (Daily)")]
    public Dictionary<string, DataItem> TimeSeriesDaily { get; set; }
}     

[DataContract]
public class MetaData
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string _1Information { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
    public string _2Symbol { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
    public string _3LastRefreshed { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("4. Output Size")]
    public string _4OutputSize { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("5. Time Zone")]
    public string _5TimeZone { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class DataItem
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public string _1Open { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public string _2High { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public string _3Low { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public string _4Close { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
    public string _5Volume { get; set; }
}
```

And then to parse your JSON and return the list you should do like this:

```
public List<Root> ParseJson(string json)
{
    Root obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.Deserialize<Root>(json);
    return new List<Root> { obj };
}
```

Comment: Root obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response).  thank you this fixed it, I think i got stuck thinkging it was an array for some reason

Comment: @ob7777 Thanks for the update. If it helps you, please, mark the answer as the correct one.

Comment: I also tried to turn it into list by just running a enumerator and adding the a list :     if (obj is IEnumerable)
                {
                    List<object> list = new List<object>();
                    var enumerator = ((IEnumerable)obj).GetEnumerator();
                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        list.Add(enumerator.Current);
                    }
                }
 but it it says my object is not inumerable

Comment: And what do you expect to have as an item from this JSON? I edited my answer, maybe it will help. Please, edit your question and add your `Root` class there.

Comment: ok here is the json from the url

Comment: public class Root 
    {
        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
        public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("Time Series (Daily)")]
        public TimeSeriesDaily TimeSeriesDaily { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @ob7777 please, press `Edit` on your post and put it there

Comment: ok tnx I added the class sample to the post via edit

Comment: the objective is to return a List of object of the strongly type that the json returns, now that I deserlizeit into obj , thats good but I need it to be a List<Rootismyclassname>

Comment: Please, update your post and specify there all info that you need at the end. Looks like you autogenerate your classes online and it's not correct.  TimeSeriesDaily should have a type Dictionary<string, Your object that contains fields 1open, 2high ...> . If you need an array after parsing then you can extract parsing to the method and return new List<root> { OBJTEST };

Comment: not sure what else I can add here I believe you understand, that Im trying to turn the json output that you have a sample of into a strongly typed list object of that type that one can iterate over

Comment: So, I updated my answer. I believe I understood you right.

Comment: thank you , I see so in this case then I dont need this like that returns it into an object

Comment: I added the above suggestions and it returns a list object directly from the json string

Comment: how much bit coin should I send you?

Comment: Possible workaround: wrap response JSON into a square bracket( $"[ { json } ]" )

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    string json = string.Empty;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var baseAddress = "https://www.alphavantage.co";
        var api = "/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo";

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
        var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
        var response = client.GetAsync(api).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    Data data =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

and you can get TimeSeriesDaily list

```
List<TimeSeriesDaily> timeSeriesDaily = data.TimeSeriesDaily.Select(tsd => AddDate(tsd) ).ToList();

private TimeSeriesDaily AddDate(KeyValuePair<string, TimeSeriesDaily> tsdd)
{
    var tsd=tsdd.Value;
    tsd.Date=tsdd.Key;
    return tsd;
}
```

classes

```
public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
        public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Time Series (Daily)")]
        public Dictionary<string, TimeSeriesDaily> TimeSeriesDaily { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MetaData
    {
        [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
        public string The1Information { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
        public string The2Symbol { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
        public DateTimeOffset The3LastRefreshed { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("4. Output Size")]
        public string The4OutputSize { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("5. Time Zone")]
        public string The5TimeZone { get; set; }
    }

public partial class TimeSeriesDaily
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Date { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public string The1Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public string The2High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public string The3Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public string The4Close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
    public long The5Volume { get; set; }
}
```